# Dynamically setting div height to match other div

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS, but here is a basic structure of what I'm trying to do. I currently have two "child" divs arranged in a row-based flexbox layout controlled by the "parent" div. One child div has images in it, and the other has text. My goal is for the dimensions of the images to be set *relative to size of the text*, so that if I increase/decrease the size of the text, the images increase/decrease in tandem.

I would have thought this would have been accomplished with `height: auto` and `height: 100%` in various places, like so:

HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-img">
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="child-txt">
    <p>Title Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (ignoring flexbox code, just focusing on height):

```css
.parent {
  height: auto;
}

.child-img {
  height: 100%;
}

.child-txt {
  height: auto;
}

img {
  height: 50%;
}

p {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

The "logic" as I would have thought of it is:

- `.child-txt` has its `height` set to `auto`, meaning it will resize to fit the height of the content within it, in this case the `<p>` block whose `font-size` is `xx-large`
- `.parent` has its `height` set to `auto`, meaning the same thing - it should inherit the height of `.child-txt`
- `.child-img` has its `height` set to `100%`, meaning it should take up the full vertical space of `.parent`
- `img` has its `height` set to `50%`, meaning it should take up half the vertical space of `.child-img`

However, actually structuring things this way allows the images to grow to their full sizes, suggesting that `.child-img` isn't limiting its height based on `.parent`. Why is that? Is there another way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question. Also, `height:auto` means that browser would determine the height depending on context. You probably wanted `height:fit-content`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotation mark on the parent class:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-img">
    <img src="path_to_image1.jpg" alt="Description of image1">
    <img src="path_to_image2.jpg" alt="Description of image2">
  </div>
<div class="child-txt">
   <p>Title Text Here</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps and good luck :)